# How Oracle manages constraints and indexes bound to them

Tags: oracle, indexing, constraints

I've encountered situation that I can't understand.
I've created patch for DB, it drops constraints(private keys) and then drops indexes that are bound to constraints. It worked flawlessly few times on test environment. But when we finally run it on prod it crashed on first index. Test DB was re-created for test from production few times(but I don't know how it was done exactly) and there wasn't any problems. How it is possible that error didn't occurred while we were testing?

Comment: You ran a script (that we can't see) that executes a certain series of steps (that you have vaguely described) and got some error (that we also cannot see) on a database (that we have no access to) and you expect someone to tell you why?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that dropping a constraint also drops the supporting index, depending on how the constraint and index were created in the first place, so your script ought to check for that.

It is more robust to create non-unique indexes and then add primary and unique constraints that use those indexes, so that you can drop a constraint without losing the benefits of having an index in place.

The difference in behaviour when dropping constraints based on an existing or system-generated index is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#CJAGEBIG